# Integral for shifted argument in one variable

Tags: integration

Suppose that the integral
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n_1}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n_2}}f(x,y)\, dy\, dx <\infty\tag{1}
$$

My probably silly question is if then, for $h\in\mathbb{R}^{n_1}$, the integral
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n_1}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n_2}}f(x+h,y)\, dy\, dx 
$$
is the same as integral $(1)$.

If yes, does this automatically mean that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n_1}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n_2}}\lvert f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)\rvert\, dy\, dx \to 0, h\to 0?
$$

For my first question, my answer would be yes (it's integration by substitution using $\varphi\colon\mathbb{R}^{n_1}\times\mathbb{R}^{n_2}\to\mathbb{R}^{n_1}\times\mathbb{R}^{n_2}, \varphi(x,y)=(x+h,y)$ where $\lvert\textrm{det}D\varphi\rvert=1$).

As to the second question, I think the answer is, in general, no.

Answer (score 0):

First question: Yes, these are equal; your argument works.

Second question: No. The points you're making do show that

$$\left | \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n_1}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n_2}} f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)\, dy\, dx \right | = 0,$$ but pulling the absolute values inside the integrals changes the game.

For the integral you actually care about (with absolute value inside the integral), you may still get $0$, but it'd be for different reasons. If $f$ is continuous then the integrand $|f(x+h,y) - f(x,y)|$ does still $\to 0$ pointwise as $h \to 0$. So you'll still be able to prove convergence using [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) (together with triangle inequality) as long as $|f|$ is integrable, i.e. as long as
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n_1}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n_2}} |f(x,y)|\, dy\, dx < \infty.
$$
So your claim is true if $f$ is continuous and $|f|$ is integrable, i.e. if $f \in C^0 \cap L_1$. This combination of conditions is sufficient but not necessary; there could also be other (combinations of) criteria on $f$ that would also make your claim work.